# Using BrowserSync with only Node.js (MEAN)

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, browser-sync

Can anyone help me understand how to use BrowserSync with an already running node server?

I know that I have to proxy the server `localhost:3000` but where and how would I do that?

Since I'm not using Gulp/Grunt my best guess is proxying a running BrowserSync with express.js but what would that look like?

**EDIT:**

@RunnyYolk's answer is correct, The best way is to create a script in the package.json file that has BrowserSync proxy your node server. However the issue is more specifically how to use BrowserSync when you need to wait for a process to finish first, such as Angular compilation, *then* reload your browser.

My build process looks like this:

`"build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",`

How do I call `browser-sync reload` after that webpack compilation?

Answer (score 2):

I've had browser sync running with a few Node projects. I remember it being a little bit of a fiddle the first couple of times, but definitely worth the effort.

I can't remember exactly what I got caught on, but try these things and let me know if it's still not playing:

Assuming browser-sync is installed, make sure your app.js file (or whatever you've called it) has the server listening on port 3000.

Start the app with a command similar to this:

`browser-sync start --proxy localhost:3000 --files="public/stylesheets/*.css", "public/scripts/*.js" "public/views/*.ejs"  --no-notify`

That works for me. "--files" is a list of files for browser sync to watch, and --no-notify gets rid of some notifications that get fired on each file change - possibly useful in some situations, but I found them annoying.

Looking at this command I notice that there is no reference to `node app.js` to start up the app. I assume (although I'm not certain) that bowser-sync looks inside package.json for the "start" script. So if my assumption is correct, and if the above command isn't working for you, check that your package.json file has the script included.

Comment: Awesome @RunnyYolk! The only thing now is that Angular's compilation is not happening fast enough and BSync reloads before it's done. I need to somehow get it to reload after the build process...

Comment: Glad that helped! I don't know Angular so well, but getting browser sync to watch any files which change during the compilation process should work for you. Just add their paths to the list.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is that Angular needs to run a build process whenever any file changes. I need to fire `browser-sync reload` only after that process finishes. Perhaps streaming with `|` not sure...

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I can't help you with the Angular problem. But if you do find the solution please let me (and the community) know - Angular is next on my to-learn list, so I'm sure I'll come across the problem before too long!